# Upgrade to 16.04 caused very slow boot

Tags: boot, upgrade

After upgrading to 16.04 from a working installation (14.04) I now have issues with Ubuntu booting very slowly. I originally had a line in my dmesg output about swap participation mismatch so I followed an answer in another thread and changed my fstab to use filepath instead of UUID.

After that change, my [dmesg](http://pastebin.com/zBbPTTLN) output still has a ton of lines like the following (this was the case prior to the fstab change as well):

```
[   21.915499] Failed to send Message.
[   22.087202] Failed to send Previous Message.
```

They first begin hereabouts:

```
[    3.832472] AVX version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    3.832474] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[    3.853349] Failed to send Message.
[    3.880654] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[    3.880656] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[    3.880660] intel_rapl: RAPL package 0 domain package locked by BIOS
[    4.182891] Failed to send Previous Message.
[    4.347148] Failed to send Message.
```

And are occasionally interspersed with real messages.

I am not knowledgeable enough to make any progress from here. Can anyone advise me on how to proceed with figuring this out?

Comment: FYI, GitHub-styled fenced code blocks using ``` don't work here.